# Asp.net core hello world on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

When attempting to follow this tutorial instructions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/getting-started

I first got a missing reference issue for Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http, which I fixed by adding

"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http": "1.0.0"

under dependencies in project.json

But I still get the following issue:

error CS1061: 'WebHostBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseKestrel' and no extension method 'UseKestrel' accepting a first argument of type 'WebHostBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Please try adding this dependency in project.json: `"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1"`

Answer (score 0):

Update project.json to include

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http": "1.0.0"
},
```

Remember to run `dotnet restore` afterwards.

Ensure that the classes below have at least the following using statements:

Program.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
```

Startup.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
```

Also, for the site to be accessible outside of localhost, modify Program.cs call to WebHostBuilder to include `.UseUrls()`

```
var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                    .UseKestrel()
                    .UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:5000")
                    .UseStartup<Startup>()
                    .Build();
```